# Need regex for returning string with portion removed

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm struggling to figure out the proper regex for this.

I have a string that looks something like this:  `here-is.my.string`

I need to return a string that removes everything starting with the dash up to (but not including) the first dot.  `here.my.string`

Thanks.

Comment: If you're struggling with something, you should show your attempts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do [this](https://regex101.com/r/pO5vF8/1):

```
puts 'here-is.my.string'.sub(/-[^.]+(?=\.)/, '')
```

The trick here is the [positive look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) (`(?=\.)`), which requires that there is a dot following the match, but does not consider it a part of the match.

**Edit:**

As *Avinash Raj* and *mudasobwa* pointed out in the comments, it's enough to require a greedy sequence of characters that are not dots. [This](https://regex101.com/r/jH8yC9/1) works just as well:

```
puts 'here-is.my.string'.sub(/-[^.]+/, '')
```

Comment: i think you don't need a lookahead.

Comment: While this works perfectly, the positive look-ahead here is an overkill. `/-[^.]+/`.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby has a bajillion ways to do it. Here's a very simple way:

```
str = 'here-is.my.string'
str[/-[^.]+/] = ''
str # => "here.my.string"
```

It just finds the match and assigns `''` to it.